# Failing to mock child react component in tests

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

There are a bunch of articles and examples about this one, but for some reason, nothing seems to work.

I have a react component that has a child component. And, for simplicity's sake, I want to mock the child component in the test.

The component looks like this:

```
...
import { ProjectTeam } from '../../assignment/project-team/component';

export const ProjectOverview: React.FC<ProjectOverviewProps> = ({ projectId }) => {
  ...

  return (
    <>
      ...
        <Box flex={1}>
          <ProjectTeam projectId={projectId} />
        </Box>
        ...
    </>
  );
};
```

The ProjectTeam component:

```
export const ProjectTeam: React.FC<ProjectTeamProps> = ({ projectId }) => {
  // just a standard component... 
};
```

And here is the test:

```
import React from 'react';
import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import { generateProject } from '../../testing/generators/project';
import { ProjectOverview } from './component';
import { NGStateProvider } from '../../react/providers/route-provider/component';
import { testAngularRouter } from '../../testing/testAngularRouter';
import { DefaultProjectCollection, DefaultUtilizationCollection } from '../store/model';
import { DefaultApaActionCollection } from '../../apa/model';
import i18n from '../../testing/i18n';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

describe('ProjectOverview', () => {
  let mockStore = null;
  const project = generateProject();

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.mock('../../assignment/project-team/component', () => ({ ProjectTeam: 'ProjectTeam' }));

    mockStore = configureMockStore([thunk])({
      projects: { DefaultProjectCollection, ...{ entities: { [project.id]: project } } },
      toolUtilizations: DefaultUtilizationCollection,
      apaActions: DefaultApaActionCollection,
    });
  });

  test('renders correctly', () => {
    const { asFragment } = render(
      <NGStateProvider router={testAngularRouter}>
        <Provider store={mockStore}>
          <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
            <ProjectOverview projectId={project.id} />
          </I18nextProvider>
        </Provider>
      </NGStateProvider>,
    );
    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

My assumption, that `jest.mock(...)` should simply replace the child component in test mode. However, it does not. The whole component is trying to render as is.

Here is one of the articles I was referring to: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/mocking-react-components-with-jest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `jest.mock` call outside. I would say right at the top, just before and outside the `describe` section.

Jest needs to know about mocked component before it starts executing the test file in question.

The article which you reference, has this info,

[image]

Alternatively, you can put it within a `__mocks__` folder next to the component if that is your preference.

Comment: @ShurikAgulyansky Yeah it happens sometimes. We tend to miss these details. Glad that it worked out well for you.